# Why do we add req.user object before using a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript-6

I am understanding some basic CRUD operations on MongoDB, I am having difficulty in understanding why we use **req.user** before using a method inside the promise below -

Why can't we use return addToProduct() instead of req.user.AddToProduct()

```
exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  Product.findById(prodId)
    .then(product => {
      return req.user.addToCart(product);
    })
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `addToCart` is a method of the user object and not a variable in scope for the current module.

(And speculating, you are probably adding to the cart *of a specific user* so you need to tell the method *which* user's cart to add to.)